# Unity Game Stops On Load Same Scene Again

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have 7 scenes in my game. one of the scenes is "Playing" scene witch is my game play scene. in this game, one match includes 3 round. i save some of match data in "MatchManager" script that attached to MatchManager game object that have a singleton and don't destroy on load. other info are in a script(PSceneManager) that attached to a gameObject(PSceneManager) belong to "Playing" scene. 
In the end of each round i change some data and then I Have To Load "Playing" scene again.
HERE IS MY PROBLEM: when it loads again it stops at very beginning and even don't enter "start" function (method).
(I have a singleton in PSceneManager scrip. I delete that and even check and looking for any other static value.(there were no more static variables))

I HAVE NO IDEA WHAT IS MY PROBLEM??!(any idea can be helpful)

HEEELP PLEASE...I'M STUCKS HERE...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what the problem is. Some more information would be helpful.

If I would have had this problem I would look for the first and last moment the script still works.

Unity has already build this in for us. Just like Start() and Update() we have OnEnable() and OnDisable(). So if you add a Debug.Log() statement in those MonoBehaviour functions you know if the script and object are still active.

```
void OnEnable()  {  Debug.Log( gameobject.name + " is enabled" );  }
void OnDisable() {  Debug.Log( gameobject.name + " is disabled" );  }
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html

Comment: thanks for your guidance. I check it with "OnEnable" and " OnDisable". so it seems the script ( PSceneManager) doesn't enable again. but from what i see..., "Playing" scene loads again. because i see changes that must be done for second loading.(like changes in order of players, positions, texts, ... ) and i checked Hierarchy. it include "PSceneManager" GameObject and that object includes "PSceneManager" script that is the target script that must start working right after starting scene. every thing seems correct but "Start" method doesn't start.( I checked it with a Debug.Log)

Comment: I see another thing that maybe useful for you to helping me. in the Hierarchy i seeing a "Playing ( is loading )", even before i press play and also i can't delete that!! (remove scene doesn't work) i didn't see anything like this before. what is it for??! when i starting game, it is still there and when i stoping game another one added to hierarch : "Playing ( not loaded)!!!

Comment: Finally, i didn't found the solution and i change the structure of code.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem, and I found that before the loading of the other scene again I changed the `Time.timeScale` to zero.

I solved the problem by reassigning its value in the start of any game object of the scene that stops.